# Flutter AnimatedList with BlocListener

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, flutter-bloc, flutter-animatedlist

I'm trying to get `AnimatedList` working with my current `MessengerBloc` which can accept `MessengerEvent.pushed(Message)` and `MessengerBloc.popped(Message)`. When the state changes, it listens and compares the previous state with the current state to figure out which item index has to be added/removed/moved. Up to this point works so I removed those code for brevity.

**Problem**

When I add `MessengerEvent.pushed(Message)` this is the sequence of print statements:

`message was added`

`building messages`

`[Message()]` // from `print(messages)` in `_buildOverlay()`

`index0: []` // from `print('index$index: $messages')` in `AnimatedList.itemBuilder`

`index0: [Message()]` // from `print('index$index: $messages')` in `AnimatedList.itemBuilder`

**Question: Why is `messages` in `AnimatedList.itemBuilder` prints out `emptyList`, then runs again with the updated `messages`?**

```
class MessageOverlay extends StatelessWidget {
  final GlobalKey<AnimatedListState> _animatedListKey = GlobalKey();

  Widget _buildOverlay(KtList<Message> messages) {
    print('building messages');
    print(messages);
    return AnimatedList(
      key: _animatedListKey,
      initialItemCount: messages.size,
      itemBuilder: (context, index, animation) {
        print('index$index: $messages');
        return const SizedBox.shrink();
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<MessengerBloc, MessengerState>(
      listener: (context, state) {
        // Message moved - Removed code for brevity
        if (messageMoved) {
          print('message was moved');
          _animatedListKey.currentState
              .removeItem(prevIndex, (context, animation) => null);
          _animatedListKey.currentState.insertItem(nextIndex);
        }
        // Message added - Removed code for brevity
        else if (messageAdded) {
          print('message was added');
          _animatedListKey.currentState.insertItem(nextIndex);
        }
        // Message removed - Removed code for brevity
        else if (messageRemoved) {
          print('message was removed');
          _animatedListKey.currentState
              .removeItem(prevIndex, (context, animation) => null);
        }
      },
      builder: (context, state) => _buildOverlay(state.messages),
    ),
  );
}
```